# Jquery selector in Jsoup

Tags: jquery, jsoup

Is it possible to use selector like the below syntax in Jsoup?
Example : - **$("#test")**
I have tried using the same and getting the Could not parse query exception

Answer (score 1):

Just use `document.select("#test")`.

EDIT:
There's no way to use jQuery *expressions*. Jsoup advertises jquery-like *methods*.

Comment: I know about that . Jsoup says they have a CSS or jquery-like selector syntax. So I suppose the $("#test") should also work